# Django App is laggy when Apache2 is used vice development server

Tags: django, apache, windows-xp, mod-wsgi

The setup is:

1. Windows XP VM (Stuck with this for the time being - we're on an Intranet)
2. Apache 2,
3. mod_wsgi
4. django 1.4
5. virtualenv
6. We only have two users at most using this application simultaneously

Everything works but there is significant delay (10-20 seconds) between the browser's request and the response sent back by the server.

If I replace the Apache2 web server with the Django development server (which I do not want to do in production) the app is very responsive. So my assumption is that the problem is with Apache2 configuration or mod_wsgi configuration.

I am not an Apache expert and have spent hours looking for the right settings to configure the Apache2 web server but have failed to find anything that will improve the response.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Here are the settings that I have either changed or added to my httpd.conf:

```
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in the server process
ThreadsPerChild 10
# Changed MaxRequestsPerChild 0 to 1 for Django
MaxRequestsPerChild  1
# For Django KeepAlive should be OFF
KeepAlive Off

WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
#######################################
WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/virtual_env/sitar_env2/cissimp/cissimp/wsgi.py"
WSGIPythonPath C:/virtual_env/sitar_env2/Lib/site-packages;C:/virtual_env/sitar_env2/cissimp
Alias /static "C:/virtual_env/sitar_env2/cissimp/cissimp/static"
<Directory "C:/virtual_env/sitar_env2/cissimp/cissimp">
<Files wsgi.py>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
##########################################
```

Comment: There are many possible issues here, but a common one would be some names resolution issues. Did you tries setting the ServerName apache directive ? Does the problem happen when accessing the webapp from the server machine ? From another one ? From both ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont set:

```
MaxRequestsPerChild  1
```

You are effectively restarting Apache on every request which means having to load the whole Django application on every request. You should not do that.

Comment: From what I have read this is a recommended setting for Django. Are you suggesting this because I am using Windows? Can you recommend the proper setting?

Comment: Setting MaxRequestsPerChild to 1 is definitely not a recommended setting for Apache. Even for development it isn't really a good idea. What are you reading that says to do that. Read http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2008/12/using-modwsgi-when-developing-django.html http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/02/source-code-reloading-with-modwsgi-on.html http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode

Comment: Many thanks Graham. I checked out your blog and set the MaxRequestsPerChild to 0 and performance really picked up. The setting was a holdover from mod_python suggested configuration in the Django docs.